# I have some data in a ExcelSheet. How can I write these data in the same row which have the same value for a column?

Tags: excel, vba

I have some data in a ExcelSheet. How can I write these data in the same row which have the same value for a column?

[image]

My data is like that:

```
A  B  
1  2
1  3
5  4
5  48
7  58
8  48
8  32 
8  2
```

And I want it like this:

```
A  B  
1  2,3
5  4,48
7  58
8  48,32,2
```

How can I write this in VBA?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You shou be more specific ([ask]) and provide a [mcve] of your tries

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary to show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question. • Have a look into PivotTables too.